# WinHost, Configuration Error, 'LocalSqlServer' wasn't found in the app config or connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I've ran into a weird issue when ever I deploy to my winhost account and try to login using membership provider it works fine locally but once it's on the intarnets it breaks.

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file require to
service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your 
configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the
applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Source Error: 
Source File: machine.config Line: 148
```

It is as if I have referenced 'LocalSqlServer' somewhere in my app.config but I haven't here is my providers:

```
  <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" 
         connectionStringName="winhost" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         passwordFormat="Hashed" 
         applicationName="TestAdmin" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="2" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<authentication mode="Forms"/>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         connectionStringName="winhost" 
         applicationName="TestAdmin"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

any ideas or help is appreciated!

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bottom of your error message. It is not talking about `app.config`; rather `machine.config`.

`<root drive>:\<windows>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\config\machine.config`

This is what it looks like in mine:

```
    <roleManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: So I guess I will need to contact my hosting provider to see if they can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error deploying an ASP.NET MVC 4 site to Winhost.

The answer is to add this to your project's `web.config` file per [this link](https://support.winhost.com/kb/a813/parser-error-message-connection-name-localsqlserver-was-not-found-applications-configuration.aspx).

```
<connectionStrings> 
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" /> 
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=DBServerName;Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=DBLogin;Password=DBPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You have to add *both* the `remove name` and `add name`.